# Form send giving Error 500 after preventing spam

Tags: php, html, forms, spam-prevention, honeypot

My form was working perfectly — untill today when I found out rough way I forgot to prevent bot spam  There I went and added my usual hidden honeypot and thought the problem was solved, but nope, I created a new one! Now every time the form is send, I'll get ERROR 500 ("The page isn't working. [www.haukkaleva.net](http://www.haukkaleva.net) cannot process this request at this time.")

I took the honeypot away for a while and put back previous code, but it still keeps giving 500 — yes, the same code that was working perfectly this morning.

There's something wrong with my sender php, maybe something really obvious, but I just can't see it. Is there any fresh eyes here to help my tired ones out?

Sending lomake.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$nimi = $_POST["nimi"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$viesti = $_POST["viesti"];
$aihe = $_POST["aihe"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$ok = mail("eetu.autere@hotmail.fi",
           "Yhteydenotto kotisivuilta",
           "Aihe: $aihe\nNimi: $nimi\nEmail: $email\nViesti: $viesti");
           
if ($ok && $username == '') {
    header("Location: kiitos.php");
} else {
    header("Location: virhe.php");
}
?>
```

And the html body of the form:

```
        <form method="post" action="lomake.php">
                                <div class="fields">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="name">Nimi</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="nimi" id="name" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Break -->
<div class="col-4 col-12-small">
    <input type="radio" id="valintatuntivaraus" name="aihe" value="Tuntivaraus" checked>
    <label for="valintatuntivaraus">Tuntivaraus</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-12-small">
    <input type="radio" id="valintamuukoulutus" name="aihe" value="Muu koulutus">
    <label for="valintamuukoulutus">Muu koulutus</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-12-small">
    <input type="radio" id="valintatilaustaide" name="aihe" value="Tilaustaide">
    <label for="valintatilaustaide">Tilaustaide</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-12-small">
    <input type="radio" id="valintamuu" name="aihe" value="Muu">
    <label for="valintamuu">Muu</label>
</div>

    <p class="antispam"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Write your username" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="new-password"></p>
<!-- Break -->
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="message">Viesti</label>
                                        <textarea name="viesti" id="message" rows="3">Kirjoita viestisi sisältö tähän (tuntivaraukset, hevosen koulutus, kuvitustilaus tai muotokuva jne.)</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" value="Lähetä viesti" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </form>
```

What have I tried:

- Took honeypot away from the html and php, didn't work.
- Changed from lahetys.php to new file, lomake.php. Didn't work.
- Checked names and values, they were all good.
- Checked the code. I'd forgot one }, but adding it didn't solve the issue.
- Run through Google (also all similar topics on Stackoverflow, I know there's plenty) but nothing really helped me out. This was the breaking point that made me write my first question here ever.

Comment: You haven't checked for the reason you get the Error 500. Have a look in [the PHP error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel).

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it.

Comment: you are assuming the post values are set, I always include an `isset(...)` test with a default value/error message. As others have suggested, I'd check your php_errors.log for specific errors - you can also include 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` 
in your php source to show errors at runtime (don't leave in production code)